# nested structure name visibility

Tags: c, standards, standards-compliance

I wonder if the the following C code is valid:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        int value;
    } b;
};

struct B;

void func1(struct B* b) {
    b->value = 42;
}

void func2() {
    struct A a;
    func1(&a.b);
}
```

This code compiles with gcc and works as one might expect whereas a code checker complains and I wonder who is right and if this is acceptable by the standard (C90 or C99) to refer to `struct B` in this form.

Comment: Ignoring the nesting, `A a;` should not compile. It must be `struct A a;`. With that change, MSVC also accepts this.

Comment: Thanks, the `struct` was lost while I was formatting the post, added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you will have an error if you want use Struct B outside Struct A.